# AWS Cognito Sync with Authorised Users

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have implemented AWS Cognito successfully as below for Unauthorised users. With Unauthorised users, once the IdentityId is successfully returned I can then use Cognito Sync to create and manipulate Datasets successfully. I have been unable to use Cognito Sync with an Authorised user. Please can someone tell me how I obtain the IdentityId for a Authorised user, which then allows me to listRecords (which requires the IdentityId). IdentityId is always being returned as undefined.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: REACT_APP_AWS_CONFIG_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
});

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: REACT_APP_AWS_CONFIG_USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: REACT_APP_AWS_CONFIG_CLIENT_ID,
});

let cognitosync = new AWS.CognitoSync();

AWS.config.credentials.get(()=>{
    IdentityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
    listRecords();
});

function listRecords(){
    cognitosync.listRecords({
        DatasetName     : DATA_SET_NAME,
        IdentityId      : IdentityId,
        IdentityPoolId  : REACT_APP_AWS_CONFIG_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
    }, function(error, data) {
        //...
    });
 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you gotten a session for the authenticated user?  Have you looked at use case 4 on this page: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a JWT returned from `cognitoUser.authenticateUser(...)`. Adding the JWT to a Cognito User Pool `Login` for use with `new CognitoIdentityCredentials(...)` but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just need to add a `Logins` map to your `AWS.config.credentials` object for authenticated users.

What you put in the `Logins` map depends on how the user authenticated, but essentially you need a single entry, with the identity provider (IDP) as the key, and the id token you received from that IDP as the value.

---

For example, if your user authenticated with Google, you might have:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
    Logins: {
       'accounts.google.com': googleUser.tokenId
    }
});
```

where `googleUser` is the object returned by Google.

---

If your user authenticated with a Cognito User Pool, you might have:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
    Logins: {
        'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx': 
        session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()

    }
});
```

Where `session` is passed to a callback you provide to `CognitoUser.getSession()`.  Additional code context for this use case [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mikepatrick/6802662224bc64276cf0b289f5ad1e71).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've already tried adding a Cognito User Pool Login without success but I'm still grateful to hear your suggestion as it validates that approach, making we wonder if a setting is incorrect in the AWS console. I feel like I've tried just about everything!

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered what my problem was. To get the JWT for the `Login` key/value I was using :

`result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()`

when it should have been:

`result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()`

all is working now